# Responsive web parts possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, responsive

Is it possible for a web part to dynamically resize across a web part zone depending on the size of a computer screen the site is being displayed on?

Answer (score 2):

Yes... this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/design/grid-and-responsive-design) describes the responsive grid in Sharepoint.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)